# Hide Windows app icons in dock with VMware Fusion's Unity mode

Tags: vmware-fusion, dock

Is it possible to have VMware Fusion to not show the icons for Windows applications in the dock while in Unity mode? They can often be redundant and I would love to remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the settings, try the 'Show running virtual machine applications in the Dock' option.

[image]