# When in VMWare Fusion (Unity view) how do you place shortcuts to Windows apps on the Mac Dock or Desktop?

Tags: macos, shortcuts, vmware-fusion, dock

Running VMWare Fusion 5 under OS X 10.7.  When in Unity view how do you place shortcuts to Windows apps on the Mac Dock or Desktop?  As shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/22775/12894) previous versions of VMWare Fusion appeared had an option for this.

[image: VMWare Fusion dock options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. start the application from the guest OS
2. switch to unity view (application icon becomes visible in dock)
3. Ctrl-click the application icon in the dock and select 'Keep in Dock'